# convert Math Formulae using MathJax to save in PDF

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mathjax, mpdf

**Till Now** - We have online examination web app on WP. I am saving question paper as PDF without opening it in HTML format.

If I display question paper on webpage, its converts all the maths formula appropriately because of **mathjax.js**. mathjax.js work when the data(question paper) is on webpage. But If I try to save same question paper as PDF without opening it on any webpage, it does not work. Because mathjax.js needs data on webpage to be appeared.

**My Experiments** -
1. I tried to load mathjax.js when I am receiving data(question paper) from DB. I thought that will convert the formula back to original state. But, its not. Because, mathjax needs data to be on webpage.

2. Instead of saving as PDF, If I try to print the data(question paper), it converts the formula. Because, data is on webpage this time.

**What I Want** - I want the math formula to be appear as it is in PDF. The formula's are converted using mathjax only. So, I will have to use mathjax only to reconvert it to original state.

How can achieve this..?

```
<?php
//db connection
$dbConn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "username", "password") or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysql_error());

//db selection
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysql_error());

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

if($_REQUEST['action'] == "print") {
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results = utf8');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT question_id FROM wpc6_emp_exam_questions WHERE exam_id = '$id' ");
    $exam_details = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name, duration, passing_percent, negative_marking  FROM wpc6_emp_exams WHERE id = '$id' "));
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $results[] = $row['question_id'];
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT question, option1, option2, option3, option4 FROM wpc6_emp_questions WHERE id = '$question_id' ");
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
            $results1[] = $row1;
        }

    }   
}
?>

<!-- Mathjax Script Start -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML-full"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$", "$"],["\\(", "\\)"]]}});</script>
<!-- Mathjax Script End -->


<?php

$html .= '
    <style>
    p, div { font-family: freeserif}
    </style>
    <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="logo_3.png"></div>
    <br/><hr><br/>

    <div style="float: left; width: 70%;">Exam - '.$exam_details['name'].'</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 30%;">Duration - '.$exam_details['duration'].' Mins</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 70%;">Passing Percent - '.$exam_details['passing_percent'].'</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 30%;">Negative Marking - '.$exam_details['negative_marking'].'</div><hr>';


for($i=1; $i<=count($results1); $i++) {
    $question = $i.'. '.$results1[$i-1]['question'];
    $question = str_replace(array("\\","[","]"),"",$question);
    $question = str_replace("(","<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(",$question);
    $option1 = $results1[$i-1]['option1'];
    $option1 = str_replace(array("\\","[","]"),"",$option1);
    $option2 = $results1[$i-1]['option2'];
    $option2 = str_replace(array("\\","[","]"),"",$option2);
    $option3 = $results1[$i-1]['option3'];
    $option3 = str_replace(array("\\","[","]"),"",$option3);
    $option4 = $results1[$i-1]['option4'];
    $option4 = str_replace(array("\\","[","]"),"",$option4);

    $html .= '<p style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: freeserif "><div style="float: left; width: 100%; margin-bottom:5px; font-family: freeserif">'.$question.'</div>';

    if(strlen($option1)>40 || strlen($option2)>40 || strlen($option3)>40 || strlen($option4)>40 ) {
        $html .= '<div>(a) '.$option1.'<br/>'
            .'(b) '.$option2.'<br/>'
            .'(c) '.$option3.'<br/>'
            .'(d) '.$option4.'<br/>
        </p>';
    } else if(strlen($option1)>15 || strlen($option2)>15 || strlen($option3)>15 || strlen($option4)>15 ) {
        $html .= '<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">(a) '.$option1.'</div>'
            .'<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">(b) '.$option2.'</div>'
            .'<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">(c) '.$option3.'</div>'
            .'<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">(d) '.$option4.'</div>
        </p>';
    } else if(strlen($option1)<=15 || strlen($option2)<=15 || strlen($option3)<=15 || strlen($option4)<=15 ) {
        $html .= '<div style="float: left; width: 25%;">(a) '.$option1.'</div>'
            .'<div style="float: left; width: 25%;">(b) '.$option2.'</div>'
            .'<div style="float: left; width: 25%;">(c) '.$option3.'</div>'
            .'<div style="float: left; width: 25%;">(d) '.$option4.'</div>
        </p>';
    }
}

$html .= '<br/><br/><br/><div style="text-align: center"> --------- O &nbsp;&nbsp;Best of Luck&nbsp;&nbsp; O --------- </div>';

include("../mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('');
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('logo_1.png');
$mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

?>
```

You can ignore **Mathjax Script Start** part in the code if you want.

Any solution would be appreciable

Thanks

Comment: Why not just pass the resulting HTML through [mathjax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please elaborate a little bit..?

Comment: One approach would be to pass the resulting HTML to mathjax-node and the returned HTML to mpdf. You'll just have to figure out how to call a NodeJS tool (or a CLI tool) from PHP.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try with it.